# Building an exe with Pyinstaller and cython compiled files

Tags: python, cython, pyinstaller

I am having trouble generating an exe with cython code.  I create the cython files by running `python setup.py build_ext --inplace` in the directory where myLog.pyx is.

When I run the main.py script, without generating an exe, it works fine.

Once I created an exe using pyinstaller, 'Import myLog' is getting an error "DLL load failed. The specified module could not be found"

Pyinstaller code ran was:

```
pyinstaller --debug -c -F --onefile main.py
```

Files used are below:

Also, how come I cannot get the setup.py running right when the folder has `__init__.py` in it?

### setup.py

```
from distutils.core import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize
import os

pyx_files = []

listing = os.listdir("./")
for filename in listing:
    if filename[-4:] == ".pyx":
        pyx_files.append(filename)

for file in pyx_files:
    setup(ext_modules = cythonize(file))
```

### main.py

```
import sys
sys.path.append("./scripts/Log")
import myLog

myLog.log()
```

### ./scripts/Log/myLog.pyx

```
def log():
    print("log")
```

Comment: I think that pyinstaller creates a zip file and Python can't import compiled modules from zip files. Therefore it won't work (and there's no good solution). I'm not 100% sure though

Comment: Makes sense.  It definitely works fine if I place all the files in the main directory when running the pyinstaller command.

Comment: You get this working, I tried it and my files were way too large